# How to keep the block text in div tag refresh function?

Tags: php, jquery

I have a page that the function is to refresh div tag.
Div tag function is refresh the data will receive.

So far that's ok.

When I block the text using mouse, that's will clear the block text based on timing "20000". This below the JS script function.

```
<script src='js/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $("#content2").load("post_rf.php");
        var refreshId = setInterval(function()
        {
            $("#content2").load('post_rf.php?randval='+ Math.random());
        }, 20000);
        $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
    });
    </script>
```

What I want to do is, how to keep the block text in div refresh function ?
Because some user maybe want to copy the text. In this case, user must quickly copy the text before div refresh.

Maybe the example like facebook post live update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to assign your interval to a variable, when user mouse overs your DIV then use clearInterval, when mouse out setInterval again.

```
var interval;

$(div).bind("mouseout", function() {
    interval = setInterval(refresh, 1000);
});

$(div).bind("mouseover", function() {
    clearInterval(interval);
});
```

**EDIT**

Sorry I posted that on a phone and it's hard to write code that way, try this:

```
<script src='js/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#content2").load("post_rf.php");

        // set your initial interval to kick it off
        var refreshInterval = setInterval(function() {
            $("#content2").load('post_rf.php?randval='+ Math.random());
        }, 20000);

        // bind an event to mouseout of your DIV to kickstart the interval again
        $("#content2").bind("mouseout", function() {
            refreshInterval = setInterval(function() {
                $("#content2").load('post_rf.php?randval='+ Math.random());
            }, 20000);
        });

        // clear the interval on mouseover of your DIV to stop the refresh
        $("#content2").bind("mouseover", function() {
            clearInterval(refreshInterval);
        });

        $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: sorry 1 question, how to combine with my JS script ?

Comment: nice share Terric. Thanks. So is it possible if I use time "forever" not 20000 ?

Comment: @X-men how do you mean forever?  If you use setInterval(x, 20000) then it will loop forever, every 20 seconds. Well, until you clearInterval or leave / reload the page.

Comment: is it possible, in mouseover it keep auto refresh ?